# Excel, create duplicate indicator column based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a duplicate indicator based on three columns: ID, Country1, and Country2. Please see below data have and data want. I want to know if there is a way to create this duplicate indicator in excel. I do have a workaround to do this which I will describe below, but I want to know if there is a faster way of doing this. The data is sorted already.

Data Have

```
ID    Country1  Country2
ABC1    PHL      PHL
ABC1    PHL      PHL
ABC2    PHL      PHL
ABC2    PHL      PHL
```

Data Want

```
ID    Country1  Country2    Duplicate_Ind
ABC1    PHL      PHL    
ABC1    PHL      PHL          Y
ABC2    PHL      PHL          
ABC2    PHL      PHL          Y
```

My current way of doing this: concatenate ID, Country1, Country2. Create column with duplicate count, duplicate counter. Use where duplicate count and duplicate counter are greater than 1, this is where Duplicate_Ind = Y. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `COUNTIFS` function and without using concatenate Col A, B & C

Assume your data put in `A1:C5` include header

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2,C$2:C2,C2)>1,"Y","")
```